# How to disallow spam in tag field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

We are a a job site where we allow visitors to post Jobs / Events through various forms. However it looks like that spammers are using this process to put spam in tag fields. This has resulted into tag cloud being spammers paradise.

How can I restrict that?

Comment: Have a look at [Mollom](http://mollom.com/)

Comment: @Clive  Does it work for tag spam?  I don't think I have ever tried it for that.

Comment: @MPD I'm not entirely sure, I know they analyse content as a whole so I thought it worth a look

Answer (score 0):

If you add something like

[reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha)

to your form, that should stop the spammers in their tracks.

If the form is auto-populated by a bot, it should prevent adding spam content in any of the form fields as they won't be able to submit the form without passing the challenge.